# How to dynamically specify keys of output object based on input

Tags: typescript

I have a react hook that enriches an object with an extra key and a function to set that key. The input could look like this:

```
fn(data: {...anything }, key: 'checked', initVal: true)
```

and the output is going to look like this:

```
{
    ...originalData,
    checked: initVal,
    setChecked: (val) => // sets val
}
```

I can't figure out how to type this function so that typescript is going to be aware of the checked and getChecked properties on the returned object or if this is even possible. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost get it to work the way you want. I assumed the name `'checked'` should be configurable. You can't construct the name `setChecked` from `checked` unfortunately. You can use a more generic name (I used `set`) or you can pass in the setter name as well.

```
declare function fn<T, TKey extends string, TValue>(data: T, name: TKey, initVal: TValue) : T & Record<TKey, TValue> & {
    set(value: TValue): void
}

var r = fn({ prop:1 }, 'checked', true)
r.checked
r.set(true)
```